# ES6 - The most recommended way to change the value of variable in 'if' scope

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Before ES6:

```js
function sayHi(sex) {
  var name = 'Bob';
  if(!sex) {
    name = 'Lucy';
  }
  console.log('Hi, I\'m ' + name);
}
```

What's the best way to achieve the same function via ES6 ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `if` shorthand:

```
var name = !sex ? 'Lucy' : 'Bob';
```

Comment: If I define the **name** variable with **let**, can I update it in **if** scope ? Shorthand is not the key to the problem.

Comment: @user1975168 Thats not how scope works. `var` can be accessed and changed from anywhere inside the function block, while `let` is only accessible inside the block (including `if` and `for` loop blocks) it was declared in. It makes no difference here.

Comment: Why not the other way around? `sex ? 'Bob' : 'Lucy'`. And btw, it's called ternary operator, not "if shorthand".

Answer (score 0):

Your entire function could be wrapped in an arrow function like this:

```js
const sayHi = sex => console.log(`Hi, I'm ${!sex ? 'Lucy' : 'Bob'}`);
```

it still uses the shorthand by @donnanicolas, but the rest is more compact. It uses template strings to add the name into the string.

I also took out the unnecessary assignment to a variable, as you are asking the computer to allocate memory somewhere to store it and then delete it. It won't make a lot of difference, but you could just do it directly.

Personally I would actually do it like this:

```js
const sayHi = sex => `Hi, I'm ${!sex ? 'Lucy' : 'Bob'}`;
console.log( sayHi( true ) );
```

That way your `console.log` is not baked into your function, and you keep the nice string-generating function separate from your output function.

Answer (score 0):

ES6 version with the use of [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

```js
let sayHi = sex => console.log(`Hi, I'm ${!sex ? 'Lucy' : 'Bob'}.`)

sayHi(true) // Hi, I'm Bob.
sayHi()     // Hi, I'm Lucy.
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```